# Why do brides wear a mangal sutra?

Tags: belief, marriage

After marriage, women have to wear a mangal sutra. Why is that?

Is it obligatory?

Comment: This also --> http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125/75

Comment: as for your question of obligatoriness - it's usually a part of North Indian ceremonies, I'm not how other regional wedding traditions handle the mangal sutra, but wearing constantly afterwards is often a family-level or personal decision.

Comment: By the way, the mangal-sutra finds no mention in Vedic texts or even the Purāṇas; it appears to be a later innovation. (I'm not saying anything about whether it's good or bad, only about where to look for sources.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR While what you say is largely true, Lalita 1000 from the brahmAnDa purANa indicate she is "kAmEza baddha mAngalya sUtra zObhita kandhara". So it does have scriptural sanction. Again, Raja Harischandra could recognize his wife, Chandramati , only by way of her mangala sUtra. Harischandra is an ancestor of Rama of Raghu Vamsa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It's a Sign

Wearing the *managal-sutra* is a unique sign that a lady is married. Similar to the red powder she uses on her scalp (*maang*). It is unique because *mangal-sutras* are different in looks. It would be very difficult to find two *mangal-sutras* exactly the same.

[image: sample mangal sutar]

#### It's Holy

It was first seen in history with *God Shiva and Goddess Parvati*. It was a symbol of their holy and divine love. It was followed from then on and adopted a general rule.

#### It's a Gift

It is also one of the first gifts a man gives to his better half. It is generally made of Gold, its expensive. It symbolizes prosperity and happiness that a woman brings in the family she goes in.

#### The science behind it

It is constructed to channel positive energy into the female's mind. See [Nihil's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/121/101) for more info on that.

Comment: Just to clarify, by science you mean religious or spiritual science not modern science with proof, evidence etc right?

Comment: You should cite authentic sources.

Answer (score 8):

> The Mangalsutra is a symbolic representation of the divine deities which is Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati. As per scripture of the Mangalsutra, the gold part represents Parvati and the black beads which holds the gold represents Lord Shiva. Gold is a symbol of prosperity and well-being. Hence, it is believed that if a woman wears the Mangalsutra, she brings happiness and prosperity in the family.
>
> According to scriptures, the Mangalsutra attracts a lot of positive and divine energy. In a Mangalsutra the two golden cups are hollow from one side and is raised on the other side. The Mangalsutra is worn with the hollow side facing the body so that the positive energies are attracted towards the void of the cups. This helps to keep the body and mind healthy.
>
> By wearing the Mangalsutra, the woman gains energy and power. It connects the body to the divine Shakti which resides in the body in the form of an element, fire. This gives the woman the energy to take care of the entire family and well-being of each member.

Read more at: [Why Hindu Women Wear Mangalsutra](http://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/faith-mysticism/2013/why-hindu-women-wear-mangalsutra-036245.html)

Comment: Please be very careful when copying from external sources. See: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @shog9, I'm not sure I followed what you mean. I've given a due reference to the source I referenced it from. What else should I've done?

Comment: See senshin's edit and the link I provided in my previous comment - it is important to indicate *what* is being quoted along with its source (which you did provide). [This answer on meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-quotes/46#46) helps to explain more about why this is important.

Comment: You should cite authentic sources.