# Which activities are forbidden in Hinduism for women compared to men?

Tags: women

Women are not allowed to do several activities during their menstrual period.

Apart from those, are there any activities forbidden for women permanently compared to men?

Example: There are very less warriors like Sathyabama for doing wars. less female soldiers etc.,

Comment: Reading Vedas also

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14823/are-girls-allowed-to-learn-the-vedas

Says women are allowed

Comment: there is a big difference between learning Vedic chants and learning the meaning of Vedanta. Women are not allowed to chant Vedas, but they are not denied in learning the meanings hidden in vedanta .e.g Maitreyi was taught atma vidya by her husband Yagnyavalka