# Which mantras from Tāṇḍya Mahābrāhmaṇa can only be recited by women?

Tags: mantras, women, sama-veda

[This *Times of India* article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/astrology/mantras-chants/can-women-chant-vedic-mantras-know-the-truth/articleshow/76686081.cms) claims that certain mantras from [Tāṇḍya Mahābrāhmaṇa](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/T%C4%81%E1%B9%87%E1%B8%8Dya-Mah%C4%81br%C4%81hma%E1%B9%87a) (a.k.a Pañcaviṃśa Brāhmaṇa) can only be recited by women:

> In fact, there is nothing mentioned in the Vedas that points towards the prohibition of women from learning Vedas.
>
> People have misconceptions that reciting Vedas mantras would affect the childbearing capacity of a woman. Neither do the Vedas nor Hinduism discriminate against women. **In Hindu scripture Tandya Brahmana there are some mantras which can only be recited by women.**

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14824/2995) cites [an article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Vijayawada/women-not-barred-from-learning-vedas/article5877128.ece) from *The Hindu* that makes the same claim:

> "It is a misconception that reciting mantras from Vedas would affect child-bearing. **In fact, there are some mantras like those found in Tandya Brahmana which should be recited by only women**," he pointed out.

Which mantras from Tāṇḍya Mahābrāhmaṇa are these two articles referring to?