# why are women not allowed to do puja enter gabhara of mandir or any religious thing

Tags: women

Why are women not allowed to do puja enter gabhara of mandir or any religious thing why is their existence all tied up to a man doing things and women being in background. Are women less pious in previous janam than a man?

Comment: You can check the various posts about menstruation on this site but it is not true that women are not allowed to do Puja. They are allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can women be priestesses?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/can-women-be-priestesses)

Comment: For one that's not even fully true women are allowed to go into mandirs during periods, it's seen as unclean and inauspicious so during those times they should not go as per scripture. India was patriarchal, but women were allowed to study and look at Haritadhramasutra and Brihkandaya Upanishad. Also, Anusasana Parva states women should be treated with respect. Like obviously the life of men doesn't revolve around women nor do women around men. But, their distinct societal roles where seen as respectable.