# Why do many Hindu women put a red dot near the middle of their forehead?

Tags: practice

Why do many Hindu women put a red dot(Bindi) near the middle of their forehead?

1. What is the reason behind it?
2. Is there any benefit of Dot(Bindi)?

Comment: Related [Why don't men wear the likes of Mangal-Sutra to signify they are married?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125/467)

Comment: This question does not show evidence of research. There is a lot of information about this on Wikipedia alone. Perhaps someone could expand their answer beyond the limited scope of this question to make this page more valuable to future knowledge seekers.

Answer (score 2):

As per Hinduism the place between eyebrows is the place of soul in body. It is Aajna Chakra. Putting red Dot there signifies that woman is in soul form and wants others also to see her as soul instead of body. This is the main concept in Hinduism. This red dot also signifies powers of shakti.

Wearing red dot means

> See me as soul not as body or worldly looks.

It is the sign of soul. The person who puts it on signifies Adhyatmikta of person.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: As per Hinduism, soul resides in heart, not in the place between eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

Not just women many men put red do in between eyebrows too. However for men practice has been restricted to Devi worshipers, traditional poojaris.
It is believed that Aajna chakra is in between eyebrows also signified by Shiva's 3rd eye upon which it is customary to meditate for Moksha and Jnana.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This question is not about sources, it is about mythology.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Regardless of what this question is "about", this site has certain standards.  Answers are supposed to be backed up with reliable sources (preferably scripture), because otherwise the reader can't tell whether the answer is right or not.