# Can a married woman take out her Mangala Sutra and keep it anywhere?

Tags: culture, dharma, tradition, scripture

I have seen many of our sisters and mothers wear the **Mangala Sutra**. The question [*Why do brides wear a mangal sutra?*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/119/2995) answers why they wear it in the first place.

**But my question is:**

Nowadays we see many working women who don't prefer to wear the Mangala Sutra to work, they just keep it in a cupboard before going to work.

**Is a married woman allowed to take out her Mangala Sutra and keep it anywhere for the sake of convenience?**

What do the shastras say in this regard?

Comment: Related [Why do brides wear a mangal sutra?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/119/3500) and [Why don't men wear the likes of Mangal-Sutra to signify they are married?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks I got the significance however would be greatful if I get answer to my second and third question.

Comment: Very good question and it's answers

Comment: scriptural rules aside, one of the most important benefits of mangal sutra, is that it lets other people (especially men) know that the woman is married, hence they can avoid inappropriate interactions. if she doesn't wear it, people might treat her as an unmarried and marriage-able woman, which is improper. Same goes for kumkum (tilak), nose-ring, toe-ring (metti), way of wearing saree (madisar) etc. these are important external symbols

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No. A married woman is not allowed to remove mangal sutra for the sake of convenience.**

As you have said in the question, we see many people who do not wear mangal sutra to offices and to some social gatherings. But it is not allowed to remove it by her own will. This also applies to men who are not wearing Yagnopaveetha(sacred thread). It is not an ordinary jewel or a necklace to do so.

There are very few exceptions to remove it from her neck when her husband is alive. They are-

1. When her husband asks her to remove it to wear any other jewel and ties it again without any delay .
2. When mangal sutra is not in a good condition. i.e when it has become very thin due to wearing for a long time. A root of turmeric attached to a yellow thread should be worn before removing the damaged mangal sutra.
3. It can also be removed by a sadguru in an emergency i.e when it is damaged.

A mangal sutra should not be removed from a woman's neck just as a yagnopaveetha from a man's body. These are sacred and should not be removed at any time especially for the sake of convenience. If a woman does so, it is said that it gives some dosha and effects the health of her husband.  Suvarna danam(donation of gold) should be performed to remove that dosha.

**Source**: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEs-LO6mifc) YouTube video (Telugu).

Comment: what about after the death of husband?

Comment: Mangalsutra along with some other ornaments should be removed like bangles, toe rings and sindhoor  etc.

Comment: is it compulsory?

Comment: I think yes because wearing of some ornaments start from one's marriage like mangalsutra, toe rings(for women), ring(for men and women. Presented during marriage not engagement),  etc. They should be removed after one's spouse is dead. But these modern days, only toe rings and mangalsutra are removed widows are wearing gold ornaments too. I don't know whether it is correct or wrong.

Comment: any scriptural reference?

Comment: @vidyarthi You could ask it as a separate question. I don't have a references of removing mangalsutra but there should be one. May be other users could be able  to clarify your doubts.

Comment: @UdayKrishna Could you cite references of your recent comment tying on wrist. Mangala sutra literally means "a sacred thread".

Comment: @SreeCharan I accept your answer , if you find any reference then please append it later.

Comment: @mano The anser was explained by well learned scholar in the video I posted as a source. The scholar explains after reading the scriptures only. You can rely on it. But if you want exact verses,  scroll below to Rickross's answer.

Comment: @SreeCharan Thankyou for taking out time.

Answer (score 13):

**This is to supplement Sree Charan's correct answer with quotes from Shastras.**

The Manu Smriti says that there is no Vedic sacrament for women.But what is Vedic sacrament for men the nuptial (wedding) ceremony is that for the women.

Hence, removing the mangal sutra (which is considered as a proof or symbol of the marriage) by women, is considered as offensive as Dwija men removing their Yajnopavitas (the sacred threads).

> Manu smriti 2.67.***Vaivahiko Vidih Streenam Sanskaroh Smritah***|Patiseva Gurou Vaso Grihartho Agni Parikriya|| **The nuptial ceremony is stated to be the Vedic
>   sacrament for women** (and to be equal to the initiation), serving the
>   husband (equivalent to) the residence in (the house of the) teacher,
>   and the household duties (the same) as the (daily) worship of the
>   sacred fire.

[image]

**Update regarding the importance of wearing Mangala Sutra:**

The fifth step in a [Vedic marriage](http://www.ramanuja.org/sri/Web/VedicWeddingCeremony) is **Maangalaya Dhaaranam**.

> There is no Veda Mantram for tying the mangala sutram (auspicious
>   thread) around the neck of the bride by the groom. The latter takes
>   the mangala sutram in his hands and recites the following verse:
>   *mângalyaṁ tantunânena mama jîvanahetunâ | kaṇṭheḥ badhnami subhage!
>   sañjîva śaradaḥ śatam ||* **This is a sacred thread. This is essential
>   for my long life. I tie this around your neck, O maiden having many
>   auspicious attributes! May you live happily for a hundred years (with
>   me).**

Comment: There are some people in South who have a nuptial ceremony but don't wear mangala sutra. I guess those will argue mangala sutra is a tradition / custom that has no basis in scriptures.

Comment: @Sv yes i have read that..for those who don't wear it at all this question is not applicable ..but those who wear it as a holy symbol of marriage will have to treat it with as much importance as mentioned in the answer.