# Did Sītā and Draupadi wear maṅgalasūtra (मङ्गलसूत्र)? What's the origin of wearing maṅgalasūtra and toe rings?

Tags: rituals, marriage, tradition, women, mangalasutra

Did Sītā and Draupadi wear maṅgalasūtra (मङ्गलसूत्र) and toe rings (पादाङ्गुलीयक)?

What's the origin of the practice of a married woman wearing a maṅgalasūtra around her neck?

Also, what about wearing toe rings during marriage? How did this originate?

Which scriptures talk about wearing these? 
[image] [image]

<sub>PS. I'm **not** looking for significance or "scientific explanation" for wearing these; just want to know the origin of these traditions. Related but not duplicate:</sub>
  <sub>– [Why do brides wear a mangal sutra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/119)</sub>
  <sub>– [Why don't men wear the likes of Mangal-Sutra to signify they are married?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125)</sub>

Comment: There is a reference given in Shremad Bhagvat Purana about Sita only kept her "Saubhagya Alankar" (सौभाग्य अलंकार) i.e. Mangalsutra etc. with her and rest is given in charity by Rama. (Skanda 9 ,Chapter 11, shloka 4).The sanskrit  word used for Saubhagya alankar is "Saumangalya".

Comment: Lailitha devi has mangal sutra tied by Kameshwara(shiva).  `Kamesha baddha maangalya sutra shobhita Kandharaa.` This is even older than Sita and Draupadi. So this is not a new practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julie Leslie, the author of [The Perfect Wife](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140435980), which is a translation of/commentary on *Strīdharmapaddhati* (*Guide to the Religious Status and Duties of Women*) by Tryambaka of 18<sup>th</sup> century Thanjavur, [says](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKbCwDXMP2wC&lpg=PR7&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The *maṅgalasūtra*, the auspicious thread on which beads (usually 
>   black or gold) are strung, is fastened around the neck of the bride 
>   by the groom during the marriage ceremony (cf. PVK II.i.537). 
>   Chapter XV of the *Laghvāśvalāyanasmṛti* describes the sacrament 
>   of marriage in detail and provides the earliest reference to the 
>   marriage thread (māṅgalyatantu, v.33; Dh.kośa III.iii.p.2048). 
>   Mantras are recited to ensure the wife's fidelity to her husband 
>   and Gaurī bestows *saubhāgya* on the bride. *Saubhāgya* originally 
>   and literally meant 'good fortune' or 'prosperity', but it came to 
>   have as its established meaning (*virūḍhalakṣaṇā*) the good fortune 
>   of the happily married woman whose husband is alive. The prefix 
>   *sau*, with which the married woman is addressed, stands for *saubhāgyavatī*, meaning 'fortunate woman' (i.e. by virtue of her marriage; 
>   Baudh.gṛ.I.6.30). The *maṅgalasūtra*, the *tilaka*, and the red line 
>   of *sindūra* in the hair, are all indispensable signs of the married 
>   woman whose husband is alive; as long as he lives, they must be 
>   worn.

Re: Toe-rings, quoting [Anant Sadashiv Altekar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anant_Sadashiv_Altekar), she [says](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKbCwDXMP2wC&lpg=PR7&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Nose- and toe-rings seem to be another late development. Altekar 
>   notes the conspicuous absence of the nose-ring in sculpture and 
>   painting throughout India before the Muslim invasions. He 
>   concludes that it was originally a Muslim ornament (1978:301 ff.; 
>   cf. PVK II.i.537). By the time of Tryambaka, however, it was 
>   another indispensable sign of *saubhāgya*.

So, it's possible Sītā and Draupadī wore the *maṅgalasūtra* but not nose- and toe-rings.

Comment: But Muslims, persians, mid Asians don't wear nose rings. Most of the Persian art I've seen has very minimal jewellery.

Comment: Practice maybe limited to Asian Muslims. Check out this question on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10011).

Comment: That would mean that nose rings are more popular in asian culture where they may have originated? Also each state in India have their own kind of nose rings while Pakistanis generally don't have much culture related to nose piercings, how so?

Comment: @sv. The reson for lack of nose rings in sculptures is because it is hard to sculpt intricate small nose ring on a already docile nosed sculpture. None of the sculptures have ghoonghat, but from dramas we know that in gupta era women did cover themselves with avaghuntana.

Comment: @sv. Sita definietly wore toe rings since ramayana itself mentions it, this historian is out of her/his mind, if something cannot be credited to aryan credit it to mughals. Lol "Wearing of toe rings is practiced in India since ages. Toe rings have been a part of the Indian culture since the Ramayana times, there has been a mention of Sita, when abducted by Ravana, threw her toe ring in the way, so that lord Rama could find her. So from the Ramayana times, till now, toe rings have been a part of a married woman’s symbol."

Comment: Hello sv, need to change this. Altekar is giving false info.

Comment: @Anisha How do you know? What is your source? Do Ramayana and Mahabharata mention nose/toe rings?

Comment: @sv. Indeed valmiki does, when laxamana says that he can only identify toe rings of devi sita as well as the tine when sita throws away her jewellery. As for nose rings the sri vaishna written sanskrit poems mention nose rings on lord krishna. When islam hadn't reached south india.

Comment: @sv. This VS altekar also says that ancient india had 70 percent literacy literal lol. People are cray cray man.

Comment: @Anisha You maybe referring to [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga6/kishkindhasans6.htm#Verse22) verse. And the notes clearly says it's not found in critical edition ("This is a celebrated and controversial stanza. This is not found in ancient manuscripts or in Baroda version."). Also, it's referring to anklets (nuupure = anklets), not toe-rings.

Comment: @sv. Ok but bicchiya is a word with sanskrit etymology. You're telling me we adopted a jewellery after giving it sanskrit name?

Comment: @sv. Also nupura is word used for all anklets as well as toe rings.

Comment: Here are all langauges in india with word fir toe rings, no such jeweelery exists in mid east neither do they have word for it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe_ring

Comment: @Anisha Your evidence is pretty weak to draw any reasonable conclusion from it. Majority of dictionaries translate [nUpura](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=nUpura&lang=sans&action=Search) as anklet.

Comment: The dictionary i used uses both anklet and toe ring.

Comment: The Sanskrit word for toe-ring is [पादाङ्गुलीयक (pādāṅgulīyaka)](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&tran_input=toe-ring&script=ia&anz=100&direct=es). Show me an early Hindu scripture which uses that word. @Anisha

Comment: @sv. Such long word? That's not the only word. Many other exist too.

Comment: @sv. As for nose ring look as lalita sahasranam and the strotras of shankaracharya both mention nose rings. Even vaishnava poetry of tamil poets mentions it.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga60/ayodhyasans60.htm#Verse19): "Seetha, sporting her tinkling anklets, walks playfully. Even now, Seetha dons her ornaments, as a mark of Her passion towards Rama." - toe-rings don't make noise. So nūpura in Ramayana is a clear reference to anklets. @Anisha

Comment: @Anisha "lalita sahasranam and the strotras of shankaracharya" - how old are these? Are all works of Shankaracharya really written by him?