# What scriptures describe the wearing of the Mangala Sutra?

Tags: scripture, rituals, marriage, life

One of the most famous parts of a Hindu marriage ceremony is the tying of the Mangal Sutra.  Yet the [procedure](http://www.ramanuja.org/sri/Web/VedicWeddingCeremony) for Vedic Marriage has nothing like Mangala Sutra involved (i.e. there is no Veda mantra described for tying this thread).

So my question is, what scriptures describe the wearing of the Mangala Sutra?

Comment: It does have. Groom ties it to Bride when [“Mangalyam tantunanena mama jeevana hetuna”](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16570/3500) mantra is chanted, in South Indian marriages.

Comment: @TheDestroyer The mantra is not from vedas is what that site says, btw that sanskrit verse is just a way to say that I am tying this thread to you, for my life saftey purpose.

Comment: The webpage you linked to says that the Mangalya Dharana is one of the 12 parts of the Vedic marriage ceremony, it just says that the mangalyam tantunanena verse is not from the Vedas.

Comment: If you observe other mantras, they also look like conversation between bride and groom, brahmins and groom etc., Check my answer to marriage procedure. So what is wrong when this is like a sentence?

Comment: @Yogi I know meaning of Mantra. Some webpages claim Mantra is from Atharvaveda but i couldn't find it in Atharvaveda. They might have felt it belonged to Atharva Veda as Atharva veda describes marriage ceremonies in detail.

Comment: @SreeCharan Well they have a source from vedas while this is not backed up by source, also there is no devata mentioned in this verse.

Comment: @Yogi Your question is subset of other question and a user flagged it as duplicate. Even though it is duplicate, i upvoted your question as it is genuine. It's absolutely fine to close as duplicate of same question (whether answered or unanswered) if  same question exists on site.

Comment: Here's another related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16570/36

Comment: @TheDestroyer When I have to flag questions I don't get privilege to duplicate a question, if the other(which was asked earlier) question has no accepted or upvoted answers!

Comment: @Yogi That is the limitation of SE sites. Users don't have that privilege.